# Data indexing issue with sapply?

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
Date    EUR HIGH    EUR LOW EUR OPEN   EUR CLOSE   JPY CURNCY  JPY LOW JPY OPEN   JPY CLOSE  GBP HIGH  GBP LOW    GBP OPEN    GBP CLOSE
8/30/2016   1.12    1.12    1.12    102.56  101.76  102.50  1.31    1.31    1.31
8/29/2016   1.12    1.12    1.12    102.39  101.84  101.92  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/28/2016   1.13    1.12    1.12    101.94  100.06  101.84  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/27/2016   1.13    1.12    1.12    101.94  100.06  101.84  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/26/2016   1.13    1.12    1.12    101.94  100.06  101.84  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/25/2016   1.13    1.13    1.13    100.62  100.30  100.53  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/24/2016   1.13    1.12    1.13    100.61  100.10  100.45  1.33    1.33    1.33
8/23/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.39  99.94   100.24  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/22/2016   1.13    1.13    1.13    100.93  100.21  100.33  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/21/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.46  99.88   100.22  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/20/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.46  99.88   100.22  1.32    1.32    1.32
8/19/2016   1.14    1.13    1.13    100.46  99.88   100.22  1.32    1.32    1.32
```

And I've used the following code

```
cur<-c('EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'CZK', 'HUF', 'ILS', 
       'PLN', 'RUB', 'TRY', 'ZAR', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'COP', 'MXN', 'PEN', 'CNY', 'IDR', 'INR', 
       'KRW', 'MYR', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'THB')
i <- sapply(cur, function(y) grep(y,names(x)), USE.NAMES = F)
MergedData <- sapply(i, function(i) x[c(1,i)])
```

And what does this is arrange it separately into datastructures like this

```
>MergedData[[1]]
Date   EUR High    EUR Low     EUR Close EUR OPEN 
1/1    1.15        1.13        1.12      1.50
1/2    1.15        1.13        1.12      1.51
1/3    1.15        1.13        1.12      1.30

>MergedData[[2]]
Date   JPY High    JPY Low   JPY Close   JPY OPEN 
1/1    1.15        1.13        1.12      1.50
1/2    1.15        1.13        1.12      1.51
1/3    1.15        1.13        1.12      1.30
```

But then I noticed that MergedData[[21]] returns:

```
> MergedData[[21]]

Date    EUR OPEN    JPY OPEN     GBP OPEN   
1/1    1.15        1.50          1.12  
1/2    1.15        1.50          1.12  
1/3    1.15        1.50          1.12
```

I would really appreicate some help. I've been stumped on this for days now.

Attached is a small sample dput of my data

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1486620000, 1486533600, 1486447200, 
1486360800, 1486274400, 1486188000, 1486101600, 1486015200, 1485928800
), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), EUR.HIGH = c(1.071, 
1.0714, 1.075, 1.0802, 1.0798, 1.0798, 1.0798, 1.0829, 1.0807
), EUR.LOW = c(1.0651, 1.0641, 1.0656, 1.0706, 1.0713, 1.0713, 
1.0713, 1.0756, 1.0732), EUR.OPEN = c(1.0698, 1.0683, 1.075, 
1.0783, 1.0759, 1.0759, 1.0759, 1.0769, 1.0798), EUR.LAST = c(1.0655, 
1.0698, 1.0683, 1.075, 1.0783, 1.0783, 1.0783, 1.0759, 1.0769
), JPY.HIGH = c(113.35, 112.54, 112.58, 112.78, 113.45, 113.45, 
113.45, 113.36, 113.95), JPY.LOW = c(111.74, 111.63, 111.6, 111.63, 
112.32, 112.32, 112.32, 112.06, 112.64), JPY.CLOSE = c(111.93, 
112.39, 111.74, 112.44, 112.8, 112.8, 112.8, 113.25, 112.8), 
    JPY.OPEN = c(111.93, 112.39, 111.74, 112.61, 112.8, 112.8, 
    112.8, 113.25, 112.8), JPY.LAST = c(113.25, 111.93, 112.39, 
    111.74, 112.61, 112.61, 112.61, 112.8, 113.25), GBP.HIGH = c(1.2582, 
    1.255, 1.2546, 1.2509, 1.2538, 1.2538, 1.2538, 1.2706, 1.268
    ), GBP.LOW = c(1.2491, 1.2475, 1.2347, 1.2428, 1.246, 1.246, 
    1.246, 1.2518, 1.2543), GBP.OPEN = c(1.2541, 1.2509, 1.2469, 
    1.2497, 1.2527, 1.2527, 1.2527, 1.2659, 1.2579), GBP.LAST = c(1.2497, 
    1.2541, 1.2509, 1.2469, 1.2484, 1.2484, 1.2484, 1.2527, 1.2659
    ), AUD.HIGH = c(0.7664, 0.7666, 0.7681, 0.7684, 0.7695, 0.7695, 
    0.7695, 0.7696, 0.7597), AUD.LOW = c(0.7611, 0.7612, 0.7606, 
    0.763, 0.7622, 0.7622, 0.7622, 0.7578, 0.7552), AUD.OPEN = c(0.7645, 
    0.7628, 0.766, 0.7681, 0.7658, 0.7658, 0.7658, 0.7586, 0.7585
    ), AUD.LAST = c(0.7625, 0.7645, 0.7628, 0.766, 0.768, 0.768, 
    0.768, 0.7658, 0.7586), CAD.HIGH = c(1.3168, 1.32, 1.3212, 
    1.3135, 1.3076, 1.3076, 1.3076, 1.3052, 1.3102), CAD.LOW = c(1.3095, 
    1.3135, 1.3075, 1.3007, 1.2993, 1.2993, 1.2993, 1.2981, 1.3029
    ), CAD.OPEN = c(1.3144, 1.3185, 1.3084, 1.3038, 1.3027, 1.3027, 
    1.3027, 1.3049, 1.303), CAD.LAST = c(1.3145, 1.3144, 1.3185, 
    1.3084, 1.3023, 1.3023, 1.3023, 1.3027, 1.3049), NZD.HIGH = c(0.7266, 
    0.7334, 0.7376, 0.7327, 0.7331, 0.7331, 0.7331, 0.7338, 0.7313
    ), NZD.LOW = c(0.7174, 0.7245, 0.7279, 0.7285, 0.7249, 0.7249, 
    0.7249, 0.7243, 0.7243), NZD.OPEN = c(0.7266, 0.7301, 0.7321, 
    0.7314, 0.7288, 0.7288, 0.7288, 0.728, 0.7312), NZD.LAST = c(0.7187, 
    0.7266, 0.7301, 0.7321, 0.7315, 0.7315, 0.7315, 0.7288, 0.728
    ), SEK.HIGH = c(8.913, 8.8926, 8.9001, 8.8508, 8.8136, 8.8136, 
    8.8136, 8.7581, 8.7785), SEK.LOW = c(8.8341, 8.829, 8.8209, 
    8.7508, 8.7388, 8.7388, 8.7388, 8.697, 8.7177), SEK.OPEN = c(8.8359, 
    8.8704, 8.8233, 8.7682, 8.7513, 8.7513, 8.7513, 8.7528, 8.7424
    ), SEK.CLOSE = c(8.9044, 8.8359, 8.8706, 8.8234, 8.7648, 
    8.7648, 8.7648, 8.7513, 8.7527), NOK.HIGH = c(8.3451, 8.3486, 
    8.3375, 8.2733, 8.2712, 8.2712, 8.2712, 8.2538, 8.2672), 
    NOK.LOW = c(8.2947, 8.2885, 8.2529, 8.1923, 8.1892, 8.1892, 
    8.1892, 8.1762, 8.2189), NOK.OPEN = c(8.316, 8.3213, 8.2538, 
    8.2081, 8.2525, 8.2525, 8.2525, 8.2343, 8.2464), NOK.CLOSE = c(8.3383, 
    8.316, 8.3213, 8.2537, 8.2066, 8.2066, 8.2066, 8.2525, 8.2343
    ), CZK.HIGH = c(25.369, 25.394, 25.3584, 25.2388, 25.2215, 
    25.2215, 25.2215, 25.1215, 25.1755), CZK.LOW = c(25.23, 25.2239, 
    25.1323, 25.0175, 25.025, 25.025, 25.025, 24.954, 25.0023
    ), CZK.OPEN = c(25.2588, 25.2935, 25.136, 25.065, 25.1162, 
    25.1162, 25.1162, 25.0986, 25.0247), CZK.CLOSE = c(25.3617, 
    25.2588, 25.2935, 25.1381, 25.0547, 25.0547, 25.0547, 25.1162, 
    25.0986), HUF.HIGH = c(290.11, 290.86, 290.67, 289.12, 288.79, 
    288.79, 288.79, 287.88, 288.84), HUF.LOW = c(288.18, 288.6, 
    288.2, 286.86, 286.46, 286.46, 286.46, 285.01, 286.92), HUF.OPEN = c(288.72, 
    289.31, 288.23, 286.96, 287.45, 287.45, 287.45, 287.31, 287.01
    ), HUF.CLOSE = c(289.32, 288.72, 289.29, 288.23, 287.45, 
    287.45, 287.45, 287.45, 287.31), ILS.HIGH = c(3.7545, 3.7594, 
    3.7588, 3.7578, 3.7617, 3.7617, 3.7617, 3.7757, 3.784), ILS.LOW = c(3.741, 
    3.7445, 3.7409, 3.7384, 3.7429, 3.7429, 3.7429, 3.7508, 3.7638
    ), ILS.OPEN = c(3.7465, 3.7483, 3.7414, 3.752, 3.7598, 3.7598, 
    3.7598, 3.7757, 3.7663), ILS.CLOSE = c(3.7463, 3.7473, 3.7465, 
    3.7397, 3.7431, 3.7431, 3.7431, 3.7626, 3.7757), PLN.HIGH = c(4.0555, 
    4.0586, 4.0408, 4.0068, 4.0151, 4.0151, 4.0151, 4.0145, 4.0233
    ), PLN.LOW = c(4.0252, 4.0246, 3.9948, 3.9785, 3.9777, 3.9777, 
    3.9777, 3.9764, 3.9945), PLN.OPEN = c(4.0288, 4.0316, 3.9966, 
    3.9954, 4.0124, 4.0124, 4.0124, 3.9977, 4.0029), PLN.CLOSE = c(4.0473, 
    4.0288, 4.0316, 3.9966, 3.99, 3.99, 3.99, 4.0124, 3.998), 
    RUB.HIGH = c(59.1241, 59.6218, 59.4953, 59.0979, 59.616, 
    59.616, 59.616, 60.1122, 60.4219), RUB.LOW = c(58.6965, 59.0965, 
    59.0077, 58.5903, 58.7511, 58.7511, 58.7511, 58.585, 60.0606
    ), RUB.OPEN = c(59.0818, 59.4892, 59.2045, 58.9665, 59.3936, 
    59.3936, 59.3936, 60.022, 60.1993), RUB.CLOSE = c(58.9703, 
    59.2339, 59.3441, 58.9062, 58.9622, 58.9622, 58.9622, 59.4135, 
    60.1237), TRY.HIGH = c(3.7239, 3.7591, 3.7503, 3.7071, 3.7587, 
    3.7587, 3.7587, 3.7743, 3.7946), TRY.LOW = c(3.6752, 3.6965, 
    3.6788, 3.6618, 3.6869, 3.6869, 3.6869, 3.7191, 3.7592), 
    TRY.OPEN = c(3.719, 3.7455, 3.6838, 3.6999, 3.7371, 3.7371, 
    3.7371, 3.7695, 3.7734), TRY.CLOSE = c(3.6822, 3.719, 3.7455, 
    3.6838, 3.6969, 3.6969, 3.6969, 3.7372, 3.7695), ZAR.HIGH = c(13.4843, 
    13.5265, 13.47, 13.415, 13.4984, 13.4984, 13.4984, 13.4772, 
    13.5324), ZAR.LOW = c(13.3549, 13.3554, 13.2864, 13.2339, 
    13.2083, 13.2083, 13.2083, 13.3191, 13.3621), ZAR.OPEN = c(13.4142, 
    13.4502, 13.3106, 13.265, 13.3995, 13.3995, 13.3995, 13.4724, 
    13.4751), ZAR.CLOSE = c(13.4035, 13.4139, 13.4502, 13.3167, 
    13.2667, 13.2667, 13.2667, 13.3995, 13.4719), BRL.HIGH = c(3.133, 
    3.1295, 3.1367, 3.1267, 3.1387, 3.1387, 3.1387, 3.1297, 3.1627
    ), BRL.LOW = c(3.1136, 3.1128, 3.1174, 3.107, 3.1056, 3.1056, 
    3.1056, 3.1082, 3.1277), BRL.OPEN = c(3.1228, 3.12, 3.1296, 
    3.1185, 3.13, 3.13, 3.13, 3.1193, 3.142), BRL.CLOSE = c(3.127, 
    3.1156, 3.1203, 3.1182, 3.123, 3.123, 3.123, 3.1214, 3.1282
    ), CLP.HIGH = c(650.5, 648.85, 648.53, 640.78, 645.15, 645.15, 
    645.15, 646.97, 648.77), CLP.LOW = c(643.58, 643.77, 640.97, 
    637.29, 635.8, 635.8, 635.8, 642, 645.26), CLP.OPEN = c(650.42, 
    644.96, 644.03, 639.75, 644.36, 644.36, 644.36, 642.68, 648.06
    ), CLP.CLOSE = c(646.27, 648.03, 647.45, 640.25, 638.88, 
    638.88, 638.88, 643.6, 647.32), COP.HIGH = c(2881, 2889.4, 
    2879.05, 2862.9, 2883.75, 2883.75, 2883.75, 2905.15, 2920.5
    ), COP.LOW = c(2858.21, 2851.8, 2851.27, 2842.8, 2844.61, 
    2844.61, 2844.61, 2871.73, 2903.25), COP.OPEN = c(2880.5, 
    2856, 2856.81, 2861.5, 2870.63, 2870.63, 2870.63, 2898, 2920.5
    ), COP.CLOSE = c(2860.81, 2880.69, 2856.27, 2856.4, 2851.81, 
    2851.81, 2851.81, 2877.9, 2905.33), MXN.HIGH = c(20.5377, 
    20.6891, 20.7469, 20.648, 20.6013, 20.6013, 20.6013, 20.7467, 
    20.8452), MXN.LOW = c(20.3062, 20.4437, 20.5432, 20.3093, 
    20.2845, 20.2845, 20.2845, 20.4369, 20.6601), MXN.OPEN = c(20.4792, 
    20.6208, 20.5618, 20.3722, 20.5602, 20.5602, 20.5602, 20.7074, 
    20.8325), MXN.CLOSE = c(20.3504, 20.4793, 20.6208, 20.5634, 
    20.3631, 20.3631, 20.3631, 20.5602, 20.7074), PEN.HIGH = c(3.279, 
    3.301, 3.297, 3.3055, 3.2615, 3.2615, 3.2615, 3.267, 3.2755
    ), PEN.LOW = c(3.2635, 3.2805, 3.287, 3.2665, 3.237, 3.237, 
    3.237, 3.243, 3.264), PEN.OPEN = c(3.2745, 3.299, 3.297, 
    3.268, 3.246, 3.246, 3.246, 3.267, 3.27), PEN.CLOSE = c(3.268, 
    3.2855, 3.296, 3.288, 3.26, 3.26, 3.26, 3.2485, 3.2705), 
    CNY.HIGH = c(6.8764, 6.8923, 6.8853, 6.8683, 6.8742, 6.8742, 
    6.8742, 6.8842, 6.8842), CNY.LOW = c(6.86, 6.8638, 6.8625, 
    6.8562, 6.864, 6.864, 6.864, 6.8715, 6.8715), CNY.OPEN = c(6.8702, 
    6.885, 6.8642, 6.8562, 6.864, 6.864, 6.864, 6.8715, 6.8715
    ), CNY.CLOSE = c(6.8692, 6.8638, 6.8853, 6.863, 6.8672, 6.8672, 
    6.8672, 6.884, 6.884), IDR.HIGH = c(13325, 13343, 13338, 
    13350, 13375, 13375, 13375, 13380, 13387), IDR.LOW = c(13290, 
    13325, 13313, 13319, 13340, 13340, 13340, 13350, 13338), 
    IDR.OPEN = c(13315, 13338, 13325, 13330, 13370, 13370, 13370, 
    13373, 13340), IDR.CLOSE = c(13297, 13327, 13329, 13320, 
    13345, 13345, 13345, 13353, 13372), INR.HIGH = c(67.065, 
    67.375, 67.4413, 67.2325, 67.42, 67.42, 67.42, 67.5088, 67.6825
    ), INR.LOW = c(66.845, 67.185, 67.2888, 67.1475, 67.2863, 
    67.2863, 67.2863, 67.3725, 67.465), INR.OPEN = c(67.0475, 
    67.3712, 67.2938, 67.2175, 67.345, 67.345, 67.345, 67.4238, 
    67.645), INR.CLOSE = c(66.85, 67.1888, 67.41, 67.2188, 67.3188, 
    67.3188, 67.3188, 67.3737, 67.4738), KRW.HIGH = c(1148.5, 
    1147.9, 1145.65, 1140.25, 1149.07, 1149.07, 1149.07, 1154.63, 
    1158.9), KRW.LOW = c(1142.85, 1142.07, 1135, 1135.75, 1143.5, 
    1143.5, 1143.5, 1145.47, 1151.35), KRW.OPEN = c(1146, 1145, 
    1135, 1140.03, 1143.5, 1143.5, 1143.5, 1154, 1151.4), KRW.CLOSE = c(1146.15, 
    1147.07, 1144.18, 1138.07, 1147.4, 1147.4, 1147.4, 1146.93, 
    1158.22), MYR.HIGH = c(4.4447, 4.4447, 4.4418, 4.4288, 4.428, 
    4.428, 4.428, 4.4415, 4.4305), MYR.LOW = c(4.4352, 4.4352, 
    4.4275, 4.4198, 4.4213, 4.4213, 4.4213, 4.4218, 4.426), MYR.OPEN = c(4.4402, 
    4.4402, 4.4275, 4.4268, 4.4213, 4.4213, 4.4213, 4.4305, 4.4279
    ), MYR.CLOSE = c(4.4395, 4.4395, 4.4353, 4.4265, 4.428, 4.428, 
    4.428, 4.423, 4.4285), SGD.HIGH = c(1.4206, 1.4197, 1.4199, 
    1.4128, 1.4155, 1.4155, 1.4155, 1.4134, 1.4168), SGD.LOW = c(1.4136, 
    1.4137, 1.4087, 1.4054, 1.4055, 1.4055, 1.4055, 1.4079, 1.4084
    ), SGD.OPEN = c(1.4166, 1.4181, 1.4092, 1.4095, 1.4114, 1.4114, 
    1.4114, 1.4129, 1.4098), SGD.CLOSE = c(1.4205, 1.4166, 1.418, 
    1.4092, 1.4099, 1.4099, 1.4099, 1.4114, 1.4128), PHP.HIGH = c(49.985, 
    49.87, 49.783, 49.81, 49.885, 49.885, 49.885, 49.83, 49.838
    ), PHP.LOW = c(49.767, 49.645, 49.62, 49.692, 49.735, 49.735, 
    49.735, 49.723, 49.695), PHP.OPEN = c(49.83, 49.8, 49.705, 
    49.725, 49.775, 49.775, 49.775, 49.78, 49.735), PHP.CLOSE = c(49.873, 
    49.645, 49.78, 49.695, 49.78, 49.78, 49.78, 49.745, 49.83
    ), THB.HIGH = c(35.065, 35.079, 35.062, 35.08, 35.118, 35.118, 
    35.118, 35.135, 35.215), THB.LOW = c(34.99, 35.01, 34.99, 
    34.954, 35.035, 35.035, 35.035, 35.06, 35.105), THB.OPEN = c(35.065, 
    35.03, 35.04, 35.08, 35.06, 35.06, 35.06, 35.109, 35.195), 
    THB.CLOSE = c(35.004, 35.05, 35.052, 35.011, 35.07, 35.07, 
    35.07, 35.072, 35.122)), .Names = c("Date", "EUR.HIGH", "EUR.LOW", 
"EUR.OPEN", "EUR.LAST", "JPY.HIGH", "JPY.LOW", "JPY.CLOSE", "JPY.OPEN", 
"JPY.LAST", "GBP.HIGH", "GBP.LOW", "GBP.OPEN", "GBP.LAST", "AUD.HIGH", 
"AUD.LOW", "AUD.OPEN", "AUD.LAST", "CAD.HIGH", "CAD.LOW", "CAD.OPEN", 
"CAD.LAST", "NZD.HIGH", "NZD.LOW", "NZD.OPEN", "NZD.LAST", "SEK.HIGH", 
"SEK.LOW", "SEK.OPEN", "SEK.CLOSE", "NOK.HIGH", "NOK.LOW", "NOK.OPEN", 
"NOK.CLOSE", "CZK.HIGH", "CZK.LOW", "CZK.OPEN", "CZK.CLOSE", 
"HUF.HIGH", "HUF.LOW", "HUF.OPEN", "HUF.CLOSE", "ILS.HIGH", "ILS.LOW", 
"ILS.OPEN", "ILS.CLOSE", "PLN.HIGH", "PLN.LOW", "PLN.OPEN", "PLN.CLOSE", 
"RUB.HIGH", "RUB.LOW", "RUB.OPEN", "RUB.CLOSE", "TRY.HIGH", "TRY.LOW", 
"TRY.OPEN", "TRY.CLOSE", "ZAR.HIGH", "ZAR.LOW", "ZAR.OPEN", "ZAR.CLOSE", 
"BRL.HIGH", "BRL.LOW", "BRL.OPEN", "BRL.CLOSE", "CLP.HIGH", "CLP.LOW", 
"CLP.OPEN", "CLP.CLOSE", "COP.HIGH", "COP.LOW", "COP.OPEN", "COP.CLOSE", 
"MXN.HIGH", "MXN.LOW", "MXN.OPEN", "MXN.CLOSE", "PEN.HIGH", "PEN.LOW", 
"PEN.OPEN", "PEN.CLOSE", "CNY.HIGH", "CNY.LOW", "CNY.OPEN", "CNY.CLOSE", 
"IDR.HIGH", "IDR.LOW", "IDR.OPEN", "IDR.CLOSE", "INR.HIGH", "INR.LOW", 
"INR.OPEN", "INR.CLOSE", "KRW.HIGH", "KRW.LOW", "KRW.OPEN", "KRW.CLOSE", 
"MYR.HIGH", "MYR.LOW", "MYR.OPEN", "MYR.CLOSE", "SGD.HIGH", "SGD.LOW", 
"SGD.OPEN", "SGD.CLOSE", "PHP.HIGH", "PHP.LOW", "PHP.OPEN", "PHP.CLOSE", 
"THB.HIGH", "THB.LOW", "THB.OPEN", "THB.CLOSE"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Imo Oh sorry, yes. It should return EUR HIGH. I'll change it.

Comment: One issue you have is that the "PEN" currency will also pick anything that says "OPEN".  What is the value of cur[20] and i[20]?  If you provide a reproducible example, that will really help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Sorry, I'm realizing now it was 21 and not 20. You're right -- cur[21] does return PEN. i[21] returns [1]   4   9  13  17  21  25  29  33  37  41  45  49  53  57  61  65  69  73  77  79
[21]  80  81  82  85  89  93  97 101 105 109 113

I'm wondering if there is a better way do to this with a for() loop that groups every four columns instead of relying on grep? I've attached a small sample dput of my data.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue as you describe it. Firstly, it is `MergedData[[21]]` that returns too many columns. Since you seem to know this already, you should edit your question. And secondly, I don't get all the columns, but just those that contain "OPEN". As was pointed out by @thc, this happens because "PEN" matches "OPEN". You could change your regex to only match, when "PEN" is at the start of the column name: `i <- sapply(cur, function(y) grep(paste0("^", y),names(x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)`.

Comment: You are searching for "PEN" even though you also have "OPEN", so either need to pattern match more carefully (read `?regex`) or stop storing variables in column names. Also, you sometimes call the var "CLOSE" and other times "LAST". Fwiw, I'm not really sure what your question is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cur<-c('EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'CZK', 'HUF', 'ILS', 
       'PLN', 'RUB', 'TRY', 'ZAR', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'COP', 'MXN', 'PEN', 'CNY', 'IDR', 'INR', 
       'KRW', 'MYR', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'THB')
cur <- paste0("^", cur)
i <- sapply(cur, function(y) grep(y,names(x)), USE.NAMES = F)
MergedData <- sapply(i, function(i) x[c(1,i)])

> MergedData[[21]]
                 Date PEN.HIGH PEN.LOW PEN.OPEN PEN.CLOSE
1 2017-02-08 20:00:00   3.2790  3.2635   3.2745    3.2680
2 2017-02-07 20:00:00   3.3010  3.2805   3.2990    3.2855
3 2017-02-06 20:00:00   3.2970  3.2870   3.2970    3.2960
4 2017-02-05 20:00:00   3.3055  3.2665   3.2680    3.2880
5 2017-02-04 20:00:00   3.2615  3.2370   3.2460    3.2600
6 2017-02-03 20:00:00   3.2615  3.2370   3.2460    3.2600
7 2017-02-02 20:00:00   3.2615  3.2370   3.2460    3.2600
8 2017-02-01 20:00:00   3.2670  3.2430   3.2670    3.2485
9 2017-01-31 20:00:00   3.2755  3.2640   3.2700    3.2705
```